# How to screencast physical session from Windows 11 machine from macOS Ventura machine

Tags: windows, mac, display, remote-desktop, android

My goal is to have view-only access (screencast) from a Windows 11 machine's currently active physical session to a macOS Ventura machine. For more context, the Windows 11 machine is a Surface that I'm using as a writing tablet, and I typically use my Mac for everything else (including screen sharing and presentations), so the intended result is to have the Surface's screen in a window on the Mac that can be dragged around and collapsed as needed.

For those familiar with Android: before I got my Surface, I used to use the Android tablet with [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to achieve the same goal (although only the screen mirroring part and not controlling the Android tablet from the Mac).

I have explored a couple of options, but none so far works/compares directly with [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy):

1. [**Doesn't work**] Windows Remote Desktop (via the macOS client) does not let me remote into an existing physical session on the Windows 11 Surface.
2. [**Doesn't work**] Windows Remote Desktop shadowing ([as described by this article](https://woshub.com/rdp-session-shadow-to-windows-10-user/)) requires the client to also be a Windows device, not a Mac.
3. [**Unsure**] TightVNC and the TigerVNC Windows Server appear not to be actively maintained. RealVNC appears to be maintained, but is a paid service. I've set up VNC -SSH tunnels on Linux many times before, but Windows is less familiar for me.
4. [**Unsure**] AirParrot and Reflector are advertised to work, but are paid.
5. [**Unideal**] Attaching the Surface's HDMI output to a video to USB decoder on the Mac works, but is cumbersome (the Surface Book's screen does not have video out either, requiring the base to be attached).

For anyone with similar workflows, how did you set things up to achieve a "scrcpy for Windows" experience? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: RDP *can* do this, but only on Win Server. It's not a physical limitation, it's a licensing limitation [unfortunately]

Comment: Although I am not a big fan of VNC, any flavor of VNC should work and the mac clients all seem to be really good.  What do you care if they are maintained or not if it does the job?  I myself would cross that bridge when I came to it.